# How can I do a test for proportions when the data has been collected weekly from the same general population?

Tags: binomial-distribution, proportion

So I have a series of proportions taken weekly for 7 weeks. This is a study of which way spiders were facing. So for example, the first week, 20 spiders were facing out, and 10 were facing in. Now I want to test whether the proportion of spiders facing out was consistent across the 7 weeks. The population of spiders sampled were the same every week, and so they are not really independent. I know you can do a binomial test for say one set of proportions, but is there anyway to test across the whole period? I am sort of familiar with R. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you define consistency.
Suppose by consistent you mean the probability of facing out remains constant throughout the 7 weeks. A simple way then is to plot all the proportions with their C.I. and see if they overlap (then you will fail to reject the null hypothesis).

```
N=30
#xout<-rbinom(7,30,c(0.1,0.1,0.5,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.1))  ## not consistent
xout<-rbinom(7,30,0.5)  ## it is consistent
phat<-xout/N
se.phat<-sqrt(phat*(1-phat)/N)

plot(phat,ylim=c(0,1))
arrows(1:7,phat-1.96*se.phat,1:7,phat+1.96*se.phat,length=0)
```

There are 2 slight issues with this approach.

1. it is a multiple comparison thing, which you may or may not wish to adjust for.
2. It assumes temporal independence, which you can check with `acf(phat)`.

Alternatively, if you can assume a structural model, you can try to decompose the time series. `StructTS(phat)` or `StructTS(phat,type="level")`, and then you can look at the output and compare the variance of the changing slope/level (if changing) and that of epsilon. You can see `?StructTS` for the underlying model assumed.

Whichever way you do it, as you have noted, your sample size is essentially 1, so care needs to be taken if you try to generalize your finding to the wider population of spiders.